# Logstash: If-based Drop On Event After Split

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker, logstash, kibana

**The Situation:**

My input logs look something like this:

```
{
"key1":"value1"
"key2":"value2"
"events":
[{
"Level":"Information",
"Code":"100"
},
{
"Level":"Information",
"SomeKey":"SomeValue"
},
{
"Level":"Error",
"Message":"Something went wrong"
}
]}
```

**I want to:**

1. split the events array to create individual objects with all of the outer-level fields still filled in (key1 and key2).
2. selectively drop logs after the split. I only want to retain "Information-level" logs if they contain the "Code" property.

My logstash config looks like

```
filter {
 split {
  field => "[events]"
  }
}

 filter {
    if ![events][Code]
    { drop {} }
 }

 output {
   elasticsearch {}
 }
```

**The problem:**

Logstash doesn't seem to separate the events before performing the second filter.

In other words, if any of the events in the log doesn't have a "Code" field, the entire log is dropped, including "Error"-level information that I must retain.

I've been at this for about a full day and it's really getting on my nerves. I would manually try to create my own plugin, but I've never used any Ruby.

I am pretty sure this doesn't matter, but I'm running the ELK stack in Docker. I am confident that the config files load properly and that they're put to use by Logstash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually appears to be some sort of logstash bug.  Here's a demonstration of it being a bug:

Config file:

```
input {
    stdin { codec => "json" }
}
filter {
    split { field => "events" }
    if ([events] == "" or [events][Code] == "") { 
        drop {} 
    }
}  
output {
    stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
}
```

Command line:

```
echo '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","events":[{"Level":"Information","Code":"100"},{"Level":"Information","SomeKey":"SomeValue"},{"Level":"Error","Message":"Something went wrong"}]}' | bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "[main]>worker7" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Code"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.logstash.Accessors.fetch(Accessors.java:130)
    at org.logstash.Accessors.get(Accessors.java:20)
    at org.logstash.Event.getUnconvertedField(Event.java:160)
    at org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent.ruby_get_field(JrubyEventExtLibrary.java:113)
    at org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent$INVOKER$i$1$0$ruby_get_field.call(JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent$INVOKER$i$1$0$ruby_get_field.gen)
```

So basically it still thinks events is an array and it's trying to index it by "Code"

This appears to work around the issue:

```
    mutate {
            add_field => ["code", "%{[events][Code]}"]
    }
    if ([code] == "%{[events][Code]}") {
            drop {}
    }
    mutate {
            remove_field => ["code"]
    }
```

Comment: This hack did the job, thanks! Should I be worried that the hack will stop working in future updates?

Comment: This particular hack shouldn't break with new versions... it's copying a field from one location to another and then checking to see if it is `%{[events][Code]}` -- it will be that exact string if there is no [events][Code] because logstash doesn't do substitution of values that aren't set.